# <Form name="forms.{{$index}}"> not getting initialized when the ng-repeat Model changes

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

In code below when i click on "addNewEmp" i am creating new employee and adding it to the Employees model.
In my HTML i need to use $forms.['Form'+$index].$invalid.
But it shows the "undefined error" for newly created Emp form.
Please let me know if there is another way to define the Form Object?

```
<div ng-repeat=emp in employees>
<form name = forms.{{$index}}>
<button ng-click=addNewEmp() ng-disabled={forms[$index].$invalid}}/>
<form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should access form object like below if you have array of forms.

```
<form name="forms[$index]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ng-repeat` use `ng-form`.

As in

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in Employees"> 
    <div ng-form="currentItemForm">
        <button ng-click="addNewEmp()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

All things like validation, etc will be independent for each item in the repeater.

If you want to get the state of all forms, you can have a `<form>` wrapper around the whole repeater as well.

Comment: I want to access forms.$invalid . I have in UI list of rows to dis[lay. Each row has e.g EmpName,EmpDept,EmpAddr. and i have + sign next to each row to add new Employee info. But want to Disable this + sign, if the all 3 fields does not have value.Here i am using $form.invalid. But the problem is in my EmployeeListObject when i add new Emp object the Form for this particular object is not getting initialized. it should get initialized if the Main Model changes.I tried to use $apply but it is saying $apply is already in progress.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can give a name to the form and you will have this name in the child scope of each item. Then within this item you can call invalid checks and whatever.